# How to efficiently find last key and value in GTree

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, glib

I need to develop a set of functions to extend `glib2` `GTree` with:

- find first element
- find last
- find nearest (floor, ceil, greatest less than, least greater than)

Finding first is easy. You simply stop the `g_tree_foreach()` calback after first. But how to find the last element **without traversing the whole tree**?

I thought I could use `g_tree_search()` with a callback that keeps returning a positive value until found, but how do I know I'm currently on the last element?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <glib.h>

static
gint compare_int(gconstpointer p1, gconstpointer p2) {
    int i1 = GPOINTER_TO_INT(p1);
    int i2 = GPOINTER_TO_INT(p2);
    //printf("%d %d\n", i1, i2);
    return i1 == i2 ? 0 : i1 > i2 ? 1 : -1;
}


static
gboolean traverse(gpointer key, gpointer value, gpointer data) {
    //int ikey = GPOINTER_TO_INT(key);
    const char *sval = (const char *)value;
    printf("%s\n", sval);
    return FALSE;
}

static
gint find_last(gconstpointer p, gpointer user_data) {
    return 1;
}

static inline const char *NULS(const char *s) {
    return s ? s : "NULL";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GTree *tree = g_tree_new(compare_int);
    g_tree_insert(tree, GINT_TO_POINTER(10), "ten");
    g_tree_insert(tree, GINT_TO_POINTER(-99), "minus ninety-nine");
    g_tree_insert(tree, GINT_TO_POINTER(8), "eight");
    g_tree_foreach(tree, traverse, NULL);
    printf("=======\n%s\n", NULS((const char*)g_tree_search(tree, (GCompareFunc)find_last, NULL)));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `g_tree_nnodes()`should give you the number of nodes which you can use as your approach to find_first. Not so optimized though and GTree's goal ain't this.

Comment: Better alternative to glib2?

Comment: Write your own tree implementation which meets your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't want to fully implement my own tree, because I wanted to perform advanced search on `GTree` instances received from 3rd-party code.

Instead I thought that Glib authors would hardly change their internal structures these days and that I could use their fields directly.

The result is the extended version of the internal function `g_tree_find_node()` from [`gtree.c`](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/f9faac7661fb84a1c7f998a76c7e89280a17b7b9/glib/gtree.c#L1093). I added two parameters to control whether I want first, last or nearest node. The algorithm for nearest nodes differs from java's `TreeMap`, because our node doesn't have a pointer to its parent. Full code with the unit test is here: [`gtreeex.c`](https://gist.github.com/basinilya/70c0515200358e9f44f62b8f49bef898).

```
typedef enum {
    FIND_EXACT = 0,
    FIND_FLOOR = 0x2,
    FIND_CEIL  = 0x20,
    FIND_LOWER = (FIND_FLOOR + 1),
    FIND_HIGHER = (FIND_CEIL + 1)
} find_mode;

static GTreeNode *
g_tree_find_node_ex (GTree        *tree,
                  gconstpointer key,
                  GCompareDataFunc key_compare,
                  find_mode mode
                  )
{
    GTreeNode *node;
    gint cmp;
    GTreeNode *last_lesser_node = NULL;
    GTreeNode *last_greater_node = NULL;

    node = tree->root;
    if (!node)
        return NULL;

    while (1)
        {
            cmp = key_compare (key, node->key, tree->key_compare_data);
            if (cmp == 0) {
                if (mode == FIND_LOWER) {
                    cmp = -1;
                } else if (mode == FIND_HIGHER) {
                    cmp = 1;
                } else {
                    return node;
                }
            }

            if (cmp < 0)
                {
                    if (!node->left_child) {
                        if ( (mode & FIND_FLOOR) ) {
                            return last_lesser_node; /* can be null */
                        }
                        if ( (mode & FIND_CEIL) ) {
                            return node;
                        }
                        return NULL;
                    }

                    last_greater_node = node;
                    node = node->left;
                }
            else
                {
                    if (!node->right_child) {
                        if ( (mode & FIND_CEIL) ) {
                            return last_greater_node; /* can be null */
                        }
                        if ( (mode & FIND_FLOOR) ) {
                            return node;
                        }
                        return NULL;
                    }

                    last_lesser_node = node;
                    node = node->right;
                }
        }
}
```

For better performance it's possible to use preprocessor macros instead of the two new parameters, replace `if` with `#if` and include the bits header multiple times.

Comment: Curious why you are using `printf` instead of `g_print` and `sprintf` instead of `g_sprintf` (from `<glib/gprintf.h>`)?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Because I don't know GLib

Comment: No problem, glib provides about everything you need. Generally you can get away with only including the `glib.h` header and any other `glib/...h` for any specialty function you may include. They recommend not mixing `stdio` and `glib` print functions.